# Which form(s) are correct between "in case of a war" and "in case of war"?

Tags: determiners

I wonder which form(s) are correct amongst the following:

- "in case of **a** war"
- "in case of war"

Examples of use:

- "*In case of war* the economy will collapse."
- "He plans to move to Miami *in case of a war*."

Comment: They are both correct. So to would be *in case of **the** war*, if a particular war had been identified ahead of time. There is nothing different about this than how we use articles in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct but have *slightly* different connotations. "In case of a war" may imply that I'm imagining a specific war that might happen, perhaps in the near future. "In case of war" implies a more general attitude about a hypothetical future war.

A couple of other notes:

"In case of war the economy will collapse" is a bit awkward. I take it to mean "If there is a war, the economy will collapse."
A more natural example might be "In case of war, the government will conscript 100,000 men". This means "If there is a war in the future, there will be a draft".
This is a subtle difference but it's describing a planned future action, rather than just a prediction.

There is another sense of this phrase, more similar to your second example:
"I'm stocking up on canned food in case of war". This means I am stocking up *because* there may be a war. This is the same sense as "just in case".

While we're at it, "He plans to move to Miami in case of a war." is ambiguous. I don't know if you mean "If there is a war, he will move to Miami." or "He plans moving to Miami (soon) because there might be a war".

"In case of fire, break glass" is commonly written on containers for fire extinguishers. Here it *definitely* means that you should break the glass *only* if there's a fire. It does not direct you to break the glass now "just in case" there might be a fire in the future.

English is hard.

Comment: Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

Copying the answer from the comment section:

> They are both correct. So to would be *in case of **the** war*, if a particular war had been identified ahead of time. There is nothing different about this than how we use articles in general. – [Jason Bassford](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/73781/jason-bassford) [Jun 26 at 2:44](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/251990/which-forms-are-correct-between-in-case-of-a-war-and-in-case-of-war#comment473640_251990)

Comment: Respectfully disagree with the last sentence. "in case of war" has no article and is a somewhat unusual construction.